# Explanation to a proof of: $f\left(x_0+\frac{\tau}{2}\right)=f(x_0)$ for some $x_0\in\mathbb R$

Tags: proof-explanation

The problem has already been solved by a user who deleted his account so I ask a question regarding his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/647469/721644).
This was the posted problem:

Let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ be continuous & periodic with prime period $\tau>0$. Prove: $\exists x_0\in\Bbb R$ s.t. : $$f\left(x_0+\frac{\tau}2\right)=f(x_0)$$

I've read the *Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem* & the *Intermediate Value Theorem* are equivalent in some sense:

> If a continuous function is positive at some point on an interval and
> negative at another, it must be equal to zero somewhere.

His answer was accepted and applies only the tools I've heard of in the *Analysis 1* lecture so far.

The constructed function:$$g(x):=f\left(x+\frac{\tau}2\right)-f(x)$$
The part I would like to understand:
then $$\begin{aligned}g(0)g\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)&=\left(f\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)-f(0)\right)\left(f(\tau)-f\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)\right)\\&=\left(f\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)-f(\tau)\right)\left(f(\tau)-f\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)\right)\\&=-\left(f(\tau)-f\left(\frac{\tau}2\right)\right)^2\leq 0\end{aligned}$$
Did the $OP$ apply the quoted form of the *W-B theorem*?
Can I generalize the statement to a segment $[a,a+\tau]$ as in many other posts?

---

**Edit:**

Recently I've found a nice & rigorous Weierstrass theorem (regarding continuous functions on a closed interval/segment) statement. As some of my colleagues said our script isn't quite neat, I've decided to quote the author Svetozar Kurepa here in case if Croatian students ever see this post.

*literature: prof. dr. Kurepa, S.: Math Analysis, part 2: One-variable functions*
page 31, theorem no. 4:

> Let $f$ be a real function continuous on $I=[a,b]$
>
> $(1)$ $f$ is bounded on $I$
>
> $(2)$ $\exists m,M\in\Bbb R,\ x_m,x_M\in I$ s.t. $$m\leq f(x)\leq
>  M\;(\forall x\in I)\ \ \&\ \ m=f(x_m),\;M=f(x_M)$$ i.e. function
> $\underline{\text{continuous}}$ on a segment reaches its minimum & and
> maximum
>
> $(3)$ $\forall C\in\langle m,M\rangle\;\exists c\in\langle a,b\rangle$
> s.t. $C=f(c)$
> i.e., continuous function reaches every intermediate
> value on a segment.
>
> $(4)$ $$[(f(a)<0;\land;
> > f(b)>0)\lor(f(a)>0\;\land\;f(b)<0)]\implies\;\exists c\in\langle
>  a,b\rangle\;s.t.\;f(c)=0$$

$1^{\text{st}}$note: the proof is on the pages 350-351.

$2^{\text{nd}}$ note: for the proof of the first of the three statements it is crucial:
Just like the image/range of a function on a segment in a codomain:
$$R_f\in[f(a),f(b)]\subseteq\mathcal C_f,$$
any sequence $(x_n)$ contained in the preimage of a function (which is a segment) is bounded:
$$(x_n)\in[a,b]\subseteq\mathcal D_f\implies\;(x_n)\;\text{is bounded}$$

---

By the author, the intermediate value theorem (teorem o međuvrijednosti) is one
of the $4$ statements of the Weierstrass theorem given above.

Comment: Yes, the OP used the quoted theorem.  Call that thing you quoted "The intermediate value theorem".  Being "equivalent in some sense" to the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem is no reason to simply call it "the Bolzano Weierstrass theorem".  When you define $g$, show its variable ... $g(x_0) = \cdots$

Comment: @GEdgar, thank you for the response, I saw I wrote $x_0$ instead of $x$.

Comment: But you did not write $g(x)$ for your definition.

Comment: It's a special case of [universal chord theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16374/72031). You can replace $\tau/2$ with $\tau/n, n\in\mathbb {N} $ and result still holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did the OP apply the quoted form of the W-B theorem?

Yes, he used the theorem you quoted. It is usually referred to as the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem).

A more detailed proof would go as follows.

Note that the function $g$ is continuous.
By showing that $g(0) g(\frac{\tau}{2}) \leq 0$ one can conclude that $g$ changes signs inbetween $0$ and $\frac{\tau}{2}$.
Thus, by the intermediate value theorem there exists $x_0 \in (0,\frac{\tau}{2})$ s.t. 
\begin{align}
g(x_0) &= 0
\\
\implies f\left(x_0+\frac{\tau}{2}\right) &= f(x_0)\,.
\end{align}

> Can I generalize the statement to a segment $[a,a+\tau]$ as in many other posts?

Yes. The proof is almost the same as above, just replace the function $g$ by a shifted $g_a$ such as
$$
g_a(x) := g(x-a)\,.
$$